# GIT ignores commit-msg hook

Tags: linux, git, centos, gerrit, opensuse

Recently I migrated from opensuse to centos and after that GIT has started to ignore my custom commit-msg hook. It simply doesn't execute it. (I checked it by add small piece of code to "add_ChangeId" function )

- Hook generates Change-Id hash for every commit
- GIT version: 1.8.1.2
- File is located in following location: .git/hooks/
- For debugging purposes I even have set 0777 permissions to the whole .git directory

Here is the full text of commit-msg file - http://pastebin.com/zmYNi0ED

Comment: Can you execute your file without git, just running .git/hooks/scriptname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timoras you are gold. Then I tried to execute script using sh .git/hooks/scriptname it worked, but when tried to call it using .git/hooks/scriptname and shell returned that I haven't permissions to execute it.

After that I looked at fstab, and found out that have forgot to add exec flag to the partition where this file was located.

Now everything works.

One more time thanks timoras!